# Hive schema Format?

Tags: schema, hive, bigtable

Does anyone know where to look for an example of a hive schema?

Say you want to define a table with 500 columns and you've put these 500 columns in an excel spreadsheet, how can you get Hive to read in this schema from the excel spreadsheet and create the table that we want?

WE don't necessary need to tie ourselves for a spreadsheet - I am just using that as an example.

thanks.

Comment: you can just create a macro in excel to generate your `create table` SQL

Comment: @dimamah  can you help me on how can I create the macro. Thank you

Comment: here you go : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11W_ycY6ut7NbKPs39mK-Y025pU-x_PrCfXeSA4QUKDs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well its really a nice requirement, I myself faced couple of issues like this. But as far as I know here is no direct way for that. You need to create some code (Java) which will read from the source(in your case an excel spread sheet) and generate the create table statement and execute in Hive.
You might check in GitHub for some open-source projects that might have this facility. But Hive does not do that.

Hope it helps...!!!

Comment: Did you find anything ?